# Creating foreign keys in phpMyAdmin (MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, key, create-table

I'm trying to create a database in MySQL on phpMyAdmin. I am able to create the tables without any trouble, but I also want to add some foreign keys. In this case I want to link the BIDS and CLIENTS tables via the CLIENTID attribute.

```
CREATE TABLE BIDS (
 BIDID               NUMERIC(3) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
 CLIENTID            NUMERIC(3) NOT NULL
 );

CREATE TABLE CLIENTS (
 CLIENTID            NUMERIC(3) NOT NULL,
 EMAILADDRESSES      VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
 PHONENUMBERS        VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL,
 FOREIGN KEY (CLIENTID) REFERENCES BIDS (CLIENTID),
 PRIMARY KEY (CLIENTID,EMAILADDRESSES,PHONENUMBERS)
 );
```

Research has told me that the syntax is correct, but this code returns the following error.

## 1005 - Can't create table 'CLIENTS' (errno: 150)

Apparently, a solution might be involved with something called 'InnoDB'. How can I use it to fix my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Syntax is fine but problem is with `FORIEGN KEY` statement as below. You can't create FK on a non-key column. In `BIDS` table it's `BIDID` which is defined as `Primary Key` and not `CLIENTID`

```
FOREIGN KEY (CLIENTID) REFERENCES BIDS (CLIENTID)
```

So, your `FORIEGN KEY` definition should actually be

```
FOREIGN KEY (CLIENTID) REFERENCES BIDS (BIDID)
```

See a demo here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f1c9ec

Comment: Okay. So this will link the correct fields together?

Comment: Yes, per your requirement, you can as well defined `clientid` as PK in BIDS table.